# How do I clear ONLY rectangle borders? (JS , Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to clear only the strokeRect() and keep content in that rectangle.
In this example, how do I clear green rectangle without affecting the red one?

```js
 var cut = [50, 70, 100, 100]
 var cut1 = [60, 85, 60, 60]
 var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(cut[0], cut[1], cut[2], cut[3]);
 ctx.lineWidth = 3;
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(cut1[0], cut1[1], cut1[2], cut1[3]);
 ctx.lineWidth = 3;
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400px height=200px></canvas>
```

Can't figure out how..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: draw the same square with strokeStyle white?

Comment: @ChrisLi what if not a white BG ? :)

Comment: but even if there was a 'clear line' function it would leave the clear part white unless you draw something there right?

Comment: It will leave transparent iirc - the problem is this is not a `line` but your comment highlights another way to answer.. drawing the rectangle manually by lineDraw instead of `drawRect`..

Comment: your right it is transparent, didnt know that before, thanks

Comment: Canvas operations don't generate nodes as inserting HTML elements does. Instead they generate pixels on your canvas, and afterwards there is no control over these elements. The easiest way to modify the canvas is simply clear your it and redraw only the things you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas and draw the red rectangle again.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
 c.width=400;
 c.height=200;
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

 var cut = [50, 70, 100, 100]
 var cut1 = [60, 85, 60, 60]
 
 function drawRectangle(cut,fill){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(cut[0], cut[1], cut[2], cut[3]);
 ctx.lineWidth = 3;
 ctx.strokeStyle = fill;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
 }

drawRectangle(cut,"green");
drawRectangle(cut1,"red");



clear.addEventListener("click",()=>{
ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);
drawRectangle(cut1,"red");
});
```

```css
canvas{display:block;}
```

```html
<button id="clear">clear</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400px height=200px></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my problem :) But I wasn't expecting the fact of the lack of "clear stroke rect" function. It would be very useful :P

Comment: @GustavoPassos It would be very expensive too.

Comment: Take for example this pen: [Birds of a Feather](https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/dMdNvy?editors=0010). This is an extremely complex animation. If you go at line 549 you can see that the canvas is cleared once (line 557) and everything is redrawn (line 551), i.e. you delete everything and then redraw.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, clear & redraw is what you really need, but just for completeness, to clear in any shape, you can use [compositing operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

By setting the compositing mode to *destination-out*, all the pixels that should normally have been filled by your drawings will actually get rendered as transparent.

So to make a simple clear-stroke-rect:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 80, 80);

// clear
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeRect(40,40,30,30);

// set back to 'normal'
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

But using compositing, you can really clear in any shape, even from bitmap with transparency:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 80, 80);

  // clear
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.drawImage(img, 40,40);
  
  // set back to 'normal'
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
};
img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```